# Ford S-Max radio/sat nav unit identification

Tags: ford, audio, navigation

I'm really struggling to identify the model number for my radio/sat nav unit so I can find a manual online.

Can anyone help me with a model number for this unit?

[image: sat nav appearance]

Edit:

I found the manual eventually by googling `s-max blaupunkt travelpilot manual`.  [Download the manual from here](http://www.fr.ford.be/cs/BlobServer?blobtable=MungoBlobs&blobcol=urldata&blobheadervalue1=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22Nav_uk.pdf%22&blobheadervalue2=abinary%3Bcharset%3DUTF-8&blobheadername1=Content-Disposition&blobheadername2=MDT-Type&blobheader=application%2Fpdf&blobwhere=1214419634993&blobkey=id).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the information is as follows, but whether it helps you find a manual is beyond me:

```
Make:         Ford
Model:        TravelPilot EX
Part/Model:   7 612 300 516 (7M5T-18K931-AE) NOTE: The part in parens may be different
Manufacturer: Blaupunkt
```

The reason I say the one part may be different is, I found [this video](https://youtu.be/U4_46S4gYT8) which specifies for another radio which is setup exactly as yours, but the facing is different colors. Hope this helps you find what you're looking for.

Comment: Great. I had no inkling it could be blaupunkt. This is definitely useful information, thanks.

Comment: Found the manual with the keyword blaupunkt in my search. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think, if you go on the Ford website (https://www.etis.ford.com/vehicleSelection.do) then you may find by entering the VIN you should get some details about your car - whether it is sufficient not sure but may help.

Comment: I tried that (sorry, should have said in question).  The closest I get is a document like this: http://www.fordservicecontent.com/Ford_Content/vdirsnet/OwnerManual/Home/Content?bookCode=O20907&languageCode=en&marketCode=GB&viewTech=IE&chapterTitleSelected=G1419680&subTitleSelected=G1419681&topicHRef=G1409720&div=f&vCode=WF0SXXGBWSCB46205&vFilteringEnabled=True which gives information about two radio units... neither of which is like mine.  I have the same issue with the paper manuals in the car - none of them contain info about my unit.

Comment: So, have you tried a dealer? Apologies if you have...

Comment: That's the final option. I'm time-poor so don't really want to make a special trip for this.